# What do we know about $I=2^p-1-r^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Let $I=2^p-1-r^2$ where $p$ is an odd prime, $r>0$ is a natural number. We know that $0<I+1<2r$. (Let $2^{p/2}=r+f, 2^p-1=r^2+2fr+f^2-1, I=2fr+f^2 -1, 0<f<1$).

Do we know anything else about $I$?
I know this has to be related to the digits of square roots of 2 and Mersenne Numbers ($2^p-1$) but cannot make the connection.
 Can anybody help?

Comment: what is r? Why do we know 0 < I < 2r?  Thats obvious not true for so p= 3 and r = 1.  Or p = 991 are r = 7.83 x 10^97.

Comment: @fleablood I think the OP means $0 < I < 2r$ being an additional assumption.

Comment: @fleablood Sorry just edited the question to clear things up.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why $I\lt 2r-1$; can't we just keep increasing $p$ until the inequality becomes invalid?

Comment: Since 0<f<1, I=2fr+f2−1,$I<2r-1$

Comment: 0 < I + 1 < 2r is obviously not always true.  It's exceedingly easy to find counter examples.  Let p = oh.... say 7 then $I = 127 - r^2 > 2r $ for r = 1... 10.  Or my first counter example $I = 2^3 - 1^2 > 2*1$.

Comment: Why are you claiming $f$ is less than one?  Where did that come from?  If that's an additional restriction, fine.  But if $p = 7$ and $r =8$ and $2^{7/2}=8\sqrt{3} = 8 + 8(\sqrt{3} -1)$ yields $f = 8*(\sqrt{3} - 1) \approx 5.856406460551018348219570732047 > 1$.